# Installing calabash-android Mac OS X EL Capitan

Tags: android, ios, calabash, osx-elcapitan

I am getting this error when trying to install calabash-android

```
gem install calabash-android
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-android-0.5.14/.calabash_settings
```

and when I use sudo I get this !!!

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
    Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/calabash-android
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to install it, like this:

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin calabash-android
```

Comment: You should *never* install gems using sudo.https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/Best-Practice%3A--Never-install-gems-with-sudo